# JBOSS 5.0 Starting Error

Tags: jboss

I have installed Jboss 5.0.0GA-jdk6... While trying to start jboss by running "run.bat" (inside bin folder), I am getting following error... what am I doing wrong ?

```
 Failed to boot JBoss:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

    *** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error
    StandardBindings -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for
     target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[int] actual=[java.util.HashSet]

    *** DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES: Name -> Dependency{Required State:Actual S
    tate}
    ServiceBindingManager -> ServiceBindingStore{Installed:Instantiated}
    SystemPropertyBinder -> SystemPropertyBinder#1{Installed:Described}
    SystemPropertyBinder#1 -> ServiceBindingManager{Installed:Described}
    ServiceBindingStore -> StandardBindings{Installed:**ERROR**}

            at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.internalVa
    lidate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:290)
            at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.validate(A
    bstractKernelDeployer.java:174)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java
    :148)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
    394)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    15:05:41,329 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
    15:05:41,332 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
    Shutdown complete
    Halting VM
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: A handy hint for JBoss: the first line that contains a log message at the ERROR level is a good place to start - it might be worth posting that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the profile.xml

For a fix quick add the type "class=java.io.File" to the parameter of the constructor as showed:

```
<bean name="AttachmentStore"  
class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractAttachmentStore">
<constructor><parameter class="java.io.File"><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory"
  property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>
```

For a detailed explanation go to: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6981

Answer (score 0):

There is bug with incompatible version of java.You should add jre 6 in to jboss configuration file under jre folder .

Answer (score 0):

jboss 5.0.0.GA requires IBMV9 jdk.

so we can use jboss 4.3.2.GA instead . it is compatible with jdk 6 and jdk 7.