# Error while starting JBOSS 5.0.0 GA java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

```
    Getting the following exception while starting jboss server from eclipse
> ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=StandardBindings state=Described
>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[int] actual=[java.util.HashSet]
>at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:395)
>at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:153)
>at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.newInstance>(ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.java:106)
```

◾DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

> StandardBindings -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target >java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[int] actual=[java.util.HashSet] "

Comment: cannot be answered with this much details

Comment: Details added now please see what can be done

Comment: Check https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6429 also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410545/jboss-5-0-starting-error

Comment: These seems to be a different error from what I get. Found another JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6506. And this seems to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a resolution on the JBOSS site. There seems to be a JIRA open for this. Please refer to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6506

Change the bindings.xml file under:
..jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\conf\bootstrap folder.

The bindings.xml has incorrect elementClass property

```
 <bean name="StandardBindings" class="java.util.HashSet"
  elementClass="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
  <constructor>
  <parameter>
  <set>
```

The elementClass is not in the correct place. The above lines should be changed as:

```
<bean name="StandardBindings" class="java.util.HashSet" > 
   <constructor>
    <parameter class="java.util.Collection">
    <set elementClass="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
            <!-- ********************* conf/jboss-service.xml ****************** -->
```